# Wizard Control MovePrevious causing validation when CauseValidation set to False

Tags: asp.net, wizard-control

I am having a couple of issues with the MovePrevious Button in the ASP.Net Wizard Control. I am trying to prevent it from firing the validation on the controls in each step. The attempts I have tried are:

1) Setting the CauseValidation on the button to false
2) By finding the control id for the button and coding it not to fire in the MovePrevious Event in the code behind.

Neither of theses are working, and I am clean out of ideas, and would like to know if anyone has a solution to this issue.

Lastly, and this is final question, as the wizard control keeps the history, if the user returns to the first step, is there away to clean down the history in order that the wizard starts a fresh? I used the GetHistory Method, but this seems to screw up the binding of drop down lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValidationGroup property`

For your validators controls you set one ValidationGroup1
And for your button you set another ValidationGroup2

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup%28v=vs.80%29.aspx